# How to loop through many rasters in a folder and extract values using a point shapefile

Tags: r, raster

How do I loop through all rasters (TIFF) in a folder and extract values using a point shapefile which has several coordinates then have the output as a dataframe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)

files <- list.files(path=".", pattern="tif$", full.names=TRUE) # select all the tiff files in the directory
s <- stack(files) # stack all of them using r raster library
shp <- shapefile("points.shp") # read the point shape file
ext <- extract(s, shp) # extract the values from raster stack.
```

Comment: @RobertH I don't want to stack the layers, I need to loop through each of them and extract values using a point shapefile.

Comment: @jmutua you won't get different results with for loop. you could use: `mylist <- list()
for (i in files)
{ r <- raster(i)
  ext <- extract(r,loc)
  dat <- data.frame(as.vector(ext))
  mylist[[i]] <- dat
}`

Comment: @Geo-sp - that's not necessarily true. You're assuming that the rasters all have the same extent and resolution (i.e. they are stackable)

Comment: @jmutua then you should be able to use the above for loop.